# Jquery .on() method not working on dynamically created elements

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, dom

After looking at other questions and trying many possible solutions, I still have not been able to get the click event to bind properly and would really appreciate any help. I am working on a webpage that interacts with an api, no server, just making ajax calls.

This is my HTML:

```
    <div class = "img image-1 onTop" style="width:300px;left:0px">
      <div class = "pallette-container">
        <div class = "color-sample">
         <div class = "color-overlay">
           <p>#55423</p>
         </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I dynamically create these "img" divs and all the child divs when I get data back from an ajax request.

I need to bind a click event function the the 'div.color-overlay' element.

I have tried many different ways to bind it, and have reached what I think is the most specific way to grab the element with selectors.

Here is the function I wrote:

```
    $('div.img.onTop.image-1>div.palette-container').on('click', 'div.color-sample>div.color-overlay',function(event){
       var searchValue = $(this).parent().attr('data-color');
       $('#colorvalue').val(searchValue);
    });
```

Please help me understand what is wrong.  I am out of logical things to try. Many Thanks!  I am using Jquery 2.1.3.

Comment: Code looks fine to me. Are you sure the click events are not getting bound proprtly? Put a `console.log` inside your function and see if it gets logged on click. I am assuming that you think this is not working becuase the events are not bound. I see something else. I see that there is no `data-color` attribute on the `div.color-sample` element. :) That is why it `seems` to not work/

Comment: I couldn't see data-color attribute in your html.

Comment: Can you add complete HTML and JS code of how you're adding dynamic content in the DOM

Comment: _"dynamically create these "img" divs and all the child divs when I get data back from an ajax request"_ Tried attaching `click` event at `complete` callback of `$.ajax()` ?

Answer (score 1):

You started on the right track, however in order to make this work you need to bind your event handler to some higher level element, for example `body`:

```
$('body').on('click', 'div.color-sample>div.color-overlay',function(event){
   var searchValue = $(this).parent().attr('data-color');
   $('#colorvalue').val(searchValue);
});
```

The idea here is not to handle event on the element where it happened, but allow it to bubble up, in this case until `body` element, and then handle it here. These are so called delegated events.

You can read more about delegated events in [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/on/), look at section *Direct and delegated events*

Comment: YEAH!  so,  attaching it to $('body') worked!   For anyone is a similar spot- I tried attaching it to $('document') too but, no luck.   I am really curious - why does $('body') work as the parent object and not the others... what is this magic :)  THANK YOU

Comment: @BhojendraNepal Any parent element is fine. In code sample we only see the repeating elements, so it is not clear what the parent elements are, and `body` should be there anyway.

Comment: @dotnetom i would have done it with document (like i commented)why wont it work and body will work can you expand on it

Comment: @user3562480 Attaching to `$('document')` did not work, because there is no HTML element `document` in your code. I believe it would work if it was `$(document)`.

Comment: document should also work as it should be `$(document)` not `$('document')`

Comment: o my bad o added the quotes that made it invalid @BhojendraNepal thanks for explaining i didnt really thought they have any difference.

Comment: I see what I was doing wrong now, thanks so much for pointing it out.  I was dynamically creating the "img" divs.. then appending everything else to that.  So it did not work because those 'img' parent elements were not static elements that exsisted when the page loaded.   Hence - attaching it to $('body') did the trick....  lesson learned.

Answer (score 0):

> dynamically create these "img" divs and all the child divs when I get
>   data back from an ajax request.

Tried attaching `click` event after `$.ajax()` completes ?, elements appended to `DOM` ?

```
   $.ajax().then(function(html) {
    // do stuff, 
    // create these "img" divs and all the child divs
    // append `'div.color-sample>div.color-overlay'` elements to `DOM`
    $('div.img.onTop.image-1>div.palette-container')
    .on('click', 'div.color-sample>div.color-overlay',function(event){
       var searchValue = $(this).parent().attr('data-color');
       $('#colorvalue').val(searchValue);
    });
   }, function err(jqxhr) {
        console.log(jqxhr.status)
   })
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.on()` only for the elements which is existing.

One way to bind event to the dynamic elements is every time you create a element then bind event for only that element.

Another way is to bind event to the parent element